# My flutter app with Firebase authentication and google sign in is published, after publsihing Iam seeing the error "Cant use firebase authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Sir my flutter App is published but OTP and google sign in not working. I am seeing the  Error  saying
"The app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.[A safety net token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the  Firebase console. Please make sure that this application's  package Name or SHA256 paIr  is registered in the  Firebase Console.]

My flutter App has      key.jks  and key.properties

I have used this coomand and installed key.jks in my App folder

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\hp\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Also used   this command `" keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\hp\.android\debug.keystore  "`  to get SHA1 and SHA 256.

Registered the above SHA1 and SHA256 in the Firebase Console also .

In Firebase Authentication I have selected Phone provider and Google Sign In provider also .

Note : But my App is working fine when I am running my code and installing in my device  or phone  before publishing the App in the playstore. I mean to say the same code is working fine and OTP and google sign in are also working fine before publishing.

Below is the error screenshot[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: have you add SHA from play console after publishing app to firebase project?
After publish app you have to take SHA from google play console and have to add in firebase

Comment: try to get SHA from play console "setup/app integrity" and add it firebase console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you updated Android Studio, the debug key which is used to sign debug apps might have changed. Just add the new SHA-1 checksum of your debug key in the firebase console.

Easiest way would be to connect/sync to firebase from

> Tools>Firebase>Authentication>Connect>Sync

If you want to do it manually or for release keystore, first generate SHA-1 checksum using following command:

> keytool -list -v -keystore KEYSTORE_PATH -alias ALIAS_NAME

Then copy the SHA-1 checksum and go to:

Firebase Console > Your project > Settings of the app > Add Fingerprint

For more info, read this guide: [Authenticating Your Client | Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Comment: Thank You I have mistakenly  added debug keystore SHA1 and SHA256  and SHA1 and SHA256 from key.jks  retrieved    in my firebase console instead of  App signing key certificate   from App Integrity in Google Play Console .

Answer (score 0):

" keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\hp.android\debug.keystore

This command is for only debug

When you publish your app you need to add release SHA-1 and SHA-256

Try this

```dart
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```